# merge dicts for analysis

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have CSV data and should do some research with that. But I am not even able to put the data in one list or dict.

```
with open ('Probe.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=";")
            for row in reader:
                print(row)
```

Now I have every row in a dict. But how can I put these together because I have to filter them by the date later.
The data looks like this:

```
stichtag;bez;Bezirk_nam;alt;Anzahl_Personen 
2006-01-01 00:00:00.000;1;Innere Stadt;0;29 
2006-01-01 00:00:00.000;1;Innere Stadt;1;24 
2006-01-01 00:00:00.000;1;Innere Stadt;2;21 
2006-01-01 00:00:00.000;1;Innere Stadt;3;21
```

Comment: Have you heard about **pandas**?

Comment: no but I will check pandas and see if they will help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the `list` to store the individual rows in the reader.
Have a look at the code below which store every row in list `L` which you can use later for processing,

```
L = []
with open ('Probe.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        L.append(row)

print(L)
```